# Automatically send a newsletter everytime a page is updated

Tags: rss, content-management-system, newsletter

I have this page:

http://www.thedome.it/cmsms/index.php?page=alla-spina

I'd like to send a newsletter to subscribers every time this page is updated, automatically. I don't have admin privileges for this CMS thus I can't install modules, so I was thinking about a service such as FeedBurner, if only this page had a unique RSS feed (but AFAIK it doesn't, right?).

Do you know of any service/software that will allow me to solve this particular problem?

Thanks.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

To do this without access to the server you will need another server with corn jobs enabled.
If I there you I would create a simple scrape script which would also check if the content of the page have not changed. Using print version of the page may make it much easier to process. The last thing to do is to set up a corn job which would run the script at desired intervals.